# PhoneGap and GitHub

Tags: android, git, cordova, adobe

I received the student discount from GitHub therefore I can have upto five private repositories for GitHub.  Which is fine.  My GitHub says I am currently using 2/5 private repositories.

But when I tried to upload my second repository onto Adobe PhoneGap Cloud Compiler I received this message

**Unable to create app: You're using the maximum number of private apps included in this plan.
Please call customer service to discuss your requirements.**

Are GitHub private respoitories irrelevant to PhoneGap build private repositories?

Thanks a lot for your help, experts on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. PhoneGap build only allows one private app in their free account. Github has no affect on this limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  Then I am wondering, do you think there is any way to work around this?  Can one GitHub account be connected to multiple free PhoneGap account by any chance?  Thanks